# Android Gradle assembleRelease Android Replace old Apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Sorry for my Bad english

Im having problem with new Gradle For android Building application
after upgrading gradle to 3.6.3 this problem appeared .
The problem is When i change application id from gradle and call "gradlew assembleRelease "
the old apk with different application id removed from release folder and new one replaced .

in build gradle file :

release {

```
        resValue "string", "HOST_ADDRESS","${host_address}"
        resValue "string", "DOMAIN", "${domain}"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "${app_name}"
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "${defaultConfig.applicationId}.apk"
            }
        }
    }
```

in older versions , new app builded beside old one ,

i mean older apk was : com.google.app.tik4.apk
new one was : com.google.app.tik5.apk

but in new version after build completed
old one remove and new one only exists;

### because this server is online , i dont want older apks removed and have archive for my older users
please help me

PS : Anyone cant help ? im stucking here for over one month!
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since No one Helped Me Out
i tried to rename folder after each build in cmd file by Php
For users who see this question later .
Before you Call

```
gradlew assembleRelease
```

You Can Change build/output/release/apk ( or target Folder ) to another name , and by this new builded app doesnt replace old one .

i changed the folder name in my php script before call to  build new one .